# Store a date out of a docker command output in a variable and output the result

Tags: bash, docker

I would like a bash script to run and periodically check for the timestamp of a specific docker container when it got stopped the last time.
I'm at the very beginning of that script.
I have the following codeline that won't get any output on the display when executed.

```
todate=$(docker events --since "2021-01-01" --filter container=cotainername1 --filter event=stop | grep "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]")

echo $todate
```

When executing the command in the command line the output is (which is the expected output):

```
2022-02-28T17:10:22
```

The original Output of the docker command is:

```
2022-02-28T17:10:22.336669885+01:00 container stop 3f3ec3c74d453d5ff167ba988ee00960cbaea6395ccaa22e345dcb37bd3d4dc3 (image=abcdef/containername1:latest, maintainer=Mr Universe, name=containername1)
```

Comment: Maybe you need `todate=$(docker ... 2>&1)`

Comment: same result, I just don't get an output.

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from running the `docker` command at the command prompt; also, as to Mark Setchell's comment ... did you add the `2>&1` at the end of the `docker` call or the end of the `grep` call?

Comment: I presume the misspelt container name isn't the real problem.

Comment: also, update the question with the expected output

Comment: @markp-fuso Well spotted 

Comment: @markp-fuso: I have added the ouput of the docker command. I have added the 2>&1 at the end of the grep command.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: no, that was just a typo.

Comment: fwiw, the suggestion for adding `2>&1` is aimed at the `docker` command, ie, `docker ... 2>&1 | grep ...`

Comment: changed it to: 
    docker events --since '2021-01-01' --filter container=containername1 --filter event=stop 2>&1 
but still no output.

Comment: still confused ... first you state *`won't get any output on the display`* but then state *`When executing the command in the command line the output is`*; when replacing the `docker` call with `echo '....long string provided by OP ...'` the `echo $todate` shows the variable *is* populated with the line containing the datetime stamp ... ???

Comment: @markp-fuso: Sorry my English is not good enough.
Executing the command in a script file wont output anything. Executing the command in the command line gives an output.

Comment: 'works at the command line but not in the script' ... seems to suggest the script is not running under the same environment as your command line, eg, the script is not able to locate the `docker` command so an error is generated but the `grep` (effectively) discards the error message and we get no output; as an initial debugging step I'd suggest updating the script to run the `docker` call all by itself ... when you run the script this will send the entire `docker` output to the console at which point you may find more details on what's going wrong